# Modal Lifting Entire Viewport Up When Activated with React, Tailwind

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Currently having an issue with a modal in this project ([Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecommerce-site-czqttr) here). The Modal is correctly activated when the main image is clicked (note this should only be a thing in large viewports, will fix mobile after) and correctly works, however even though it is positioned Absolutely it seems to be affecting the rest of the page. The Navbar gets "squished" and everything lifts up to where there is a small gap on the bottom of the page. I set a min height of 100vh on the Main that is wrapping the two components but that doesn't seem to fix this problem.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you chose _not_ to follow the [Tailwind example](https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/overlays/modals)?

Comment: This is my first time using Tailwind so other than missing this and not realizing it existed, no specific reason at all. Is this the far better way than using the Headless UI component?

Comment: IMHO, fighting with an API that is designed to help you is never a good idea. I would stick with their recipes to accomplish your goals. You can put their example into a component - there certainly isn't any issue with that.

Comment: Thank you! Should have looked at the docs a bit more carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this tailwind trusted example model from their official [website](https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/overlays/modals)

Example:

```
<div class="relative z-10" aria-labelledby="modal-title" role="dialog" aria-modal="true">
  <!--
    Background backdrop, show/hide based on modal state.

    Entering: "ease-out duration-300"
      From: "opacity-0"
      To: "opacity-100"
    Leaving: "ease-in duration-200"
      From: "opacity-100"
      To: "opacity-0"
  -->
  <div class="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity"></div>

  <div class="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto">
    <div class="flex min-h-full items-end justify-center p-4 text-center sm:items-center sm:p-0">
      <!--
        Modal panel, show/hide based on modal state.

        Entering: "ease-out duration-300"
          From: "opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
          To: "opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
        Leaving: "ease-in duration-200"
          From: "opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
          To: "opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
      -->
      <div class="relative transform overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white text-left shadow-xl transition-all sm:my-8 sm:w-full sm:max-w-lg">
        <div class="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
          <div class="sm:flex sm:items-start">
            <div class="mx-auto flex h-12 w-12 flex-shrink-0 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-red-100 sm:mx-0 sm:h-10 sm:w-10">
              <!-- Heroicon name: outline/exclamation-triangle -->
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-red-600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M12 9v3.75m-9.303 3.376c-.866 1.5.217 3.374 1.948 3.374h14.71c1.73 0 2.813-1.874 1.948-3.374L13.949 3.378c-.866-1.5-3.032-1.5-3.898 0L2.697 16.126zM12 15.75h.007v.008H12v-.008z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-0 sm:ml-4 sm:text-left">
              <h3 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900" id="modal-title">Deactivate account</h3>
              <div class="mt-2">
                <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">Are you sure you want to deactivate your account? All of your data will be permanently removed. This action cannot be undone.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse sm:px-6">
          <button type="button" class="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-red-600 px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-red-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-red-500 focus:ring-offset-2 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm">Deactivate</button>
          <button type="button" class="mt-3 inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```